# Last row on child view controller's table view cannot select

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, childviews

I'm trying to make a view container with table view. That's works fine, but if i select the last row, the method `didSelectRowAt indexPath:` cannot be triggered. This is my code:

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "pageViewController") as! PageViewController
    addChildViewController(controller)
    controller.customDelegate = self
    controller.index = index
    self.controller = controller
    //Add Controllers
    let clientInfoVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ClientInfo") as! ClientInfoViewController
    clientInfoVC.client = self.client
    let clientRequestsVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ClientRequests") as! ClientProductRequestViewController
    clientRequestsVC.client = self.client
    let clientDebtsVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ClientDebts") as! ClientDebtViewController
    clientDebtsVC.client = self.client
    controller.orderedViewControllers = [clientInfoVC,clientRequestsVC,clientDebtsVC]
    controller.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.clientContainerView.frame.width, height: self.clientContainerView.frame.height)
    self.clientContainerView.addSubview(controller.view)
    controller.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

And this is my container view:

[image: viewcontroller]

What am I doing wrong?
Please help me

Comment: What is the white box under the table view?

Comment: Nothing, It has a constraint from view controller. It's just an empty space

Comment: I suspect that the area of the table view is smaller than the area, that cover the cells. You can prove that, if you are clipping the view of the table view to its bounds. BTW: Why you are not using container views to embed the view controllers?

Comment: I'm using embed views, this is the child view. Maybe the problem be the area?

Comment: I found the error, thanks @macmoonshine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

I needed to remove the controller's frame setting and thats it. So Just remove this line:

```
    controller.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.clientContainerView.frame.width, 
                                             height: self.clientContainerView.frame.height)
```